# How do I convert coordinates to google friendly coordinates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to do this..

```
<coordinates_east>6'01.4</coordinates_east>
<coordinates_north>45'05.5</coordinates_north>
```

I need to convert to this google friendly format in Ruby!...please note that these are not the real converted numbers just an example of the format I think I need!

```
<coordinates_east>45.46998</coordinates_east>
<coordinates_north>6.90764</coordinates_north>
```

How?

Comment: That looks like decimal degrees (although your examples are not correct). Just convert the degree/minutes/seconds to decimal degrees.

Comment: Do you sometimes have `<coordinates_west>` and `<coordinates_south>` values in addition to the east/north posted? Otherwise you don't know for which side of the equator/meridian to interpret the values.

Comment: unless the usual convention is followed ... that is, *South* latitudes are negative, as are *East* longitudes.

Comment: @pavium: meaning "west" is represented by `<coordinates_east>-6'01.4</coordinates_east>` (note the negation)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - WOW stack is good, thanks guys :-).
I'll see if I can help more.
- I don't have west and south, only east and west.
OK a better example maybe this one.

It "should" be the french ski resort of Isola 2000.

I have this,

Coordinate (e) 7'04.3
Coordinate (n) 44'10.3

It's here on google maps.

http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?hl=en&source=hp&q=isola%202000&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wl

Ultimately I need Ruby code to get them into google friendly format.

Comment: and @pavium, if I just have to convert what I've got, do you know how I could do it in Ruby code? regex?

Answer (score 2):

1. your input coordinates seem to be in wrong notation. it should probably be

   ```
   <coordinates_north>45°05.5'</coordinates_north>
   <coordinates_east>6°01.4'</coordinates_east>
   ```

   ([degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Degrees:_a_measurement_of_angle)° [arcminutes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_of_arc)'), or

   ```
   <coordinates_north>45°05'5"</coordinates_north>
   <coordinates_east>6°01'4"</coordinates_east>
   ```

   (degrees° arcminutes' arcseconds")
2. once you figured out the correct input notation, you can use [*Parsing latitude and longitude with Ruby*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317178/parsing-latitude-and-longitude-with-ruby) for converting them to decimal degrees. if your input notation is degrees° arcminutes', you have to modify it slightly. also pay attention to negative coordinates.
3. if you only want to use it with google maps, you don't actually need to convert it, because [google maps understands arcminutes/-seconds notation](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=45%B005%275%22,6%B001%274%22).

Comment: Option 3 is fine for me, I can see what you mean. They work fine as they are in google maps with the second of your examples - fine with that, (degrees° arcminutes' arcseconds"). Thing is I need to get the things converted into that form - I need the ° where I have ' and a ' where I have a . an they need " on the end!
Can you help me with a ruby command to do that, do I need gsub/regex? I'm goint to have 2,000 of these things! :-)

Answer (score 1):

my coordinates were space separated ("deg min sec") and I wrote this little lambda to handle them:

```
   @to_decimal = lambda do |str|
     deg, min, sec = str.split(" ").map(&:to_f)
     if deg >= 0
       output = deg + (min / 60.0) + (sec / 3600.0)
     elsif deg <  #HARD EARNED KNOWLEDGE HERE
       output = deg - (min / 60.0) - (sec / 3600.0)
     end
     raise "something is wrong" if output.abs > 180
     output
   end
```